# Can Print Multiple Values, But Can Not Return Them

Tags: python

I am working with a REST API that streams data, and I would like to take the relevant bits and return it (to be manipulated in another script). Here is a sample of what the raw data looks like:

```
data = {"tick":{"instrument":"AUD_CAD","time":"2014-01-30T20:47:08.066398Z","bid":0.98114,"ask":0.98139}}
```

I would like to keep the bid and the ask, and return them. To accomplish this my code looks like this:

```
def stream(data):
   bid = data['tick']['bid']
   ask = data['tick']['ask']
   return(bid, ask)

bid, ask = stream()
```

which does not work. However if I replace return with print, it prints the data just fine. Here is the relevant bit of the error message:

```
bid = data['tick']['bid'] 
KeyError: 'tick'
```

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: How do you call the function? Do you actually _use_ the result, e.g. bind it to some variables?

Comment: Your `data` object doesn't have the `'tick'` key. Check your data object -- `print data`.

Comment: You probably don't have access to the `data` variable.  Check out python variable scoping http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Variables_and_Scope.html  I'm willing to bet that the `stream()` method doesn't have access to the variable.

Comment: You're calling `stream()` without a parameter, when it expects one.

Comment: The code you've shown would raise a different error. Please post code that you've tested and the error it gave.

Answer (score 1):

The question was updated so here is a new try:

I tried to execute your code but got an error whit `bid, ask = stream()` . You have to call the function with an argument like this:  `bid, ask = stream(data)`
 which assign the values. I couldn't reproduce your error through.

On a second thought: 
If your Script with the function `stream` is called from another script, you have to take care, that the `data` variable is present in the script which calls the function.

Answer (score -1):

The return has to be within a function as it does not work outside the function.

See below which works as expected:

```
data = {"tick":{"instrument":"AUD_CAD","time":"2014-01-   30T20:47:08.066398Z","bid":0.98114,"ask":0.98139}}

def test(data):
    bid = data['tick']['bid']
    ask = data['tick']['ask']
    return(bid, ask)

print test(data)
```

prints (0.98114, 0.98139)

Comment: The question is now updated to show the return is done inside a function.